# Removing certain items from list

Tags: java, beginner

I have to co-operate with third party APIs from where I get a list and I have to remove certain elements before passing it toward.
I have a working solution but I am opened for every suggestion to make it better or more reliable (assuming the third party API maybe will change a bit in the future):

```
public List<Column> remove(List<Column> columns){
    for(Iterator<Column> iterator = columns.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();     ){ 
     Column column = iterator.next();
     try{
      switch(column.getValue()){
        case "FIRST":
        case "SECOND":
        case "THIRD":
          iterator.remove();
      }
     }catch(NullPointerException e){}
    }
    return columns;
}
```

**Edit**

Yes, it is not my production code. My production code is something like this:

```
private static final String FIRST = "first to remove";

private static final String SECOND = "second to remove";

private static final String THIRD = "third to remove";

...lots of code here

List<Column> columns = ThirdPartyLibrary.getColumns();
for(Iterator<Column> iterator = columns.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();     ){ 
     Column column = iterator.next();
     try{
      switch(column.getValue()){
        case FIRST:
        case SECOND:
        case THIRD:
          iterator.remove();
      }
     }catch(NullPointerException e){}
}
working with columns
```

I made the try and catch methods for the case if I get a column from the third party which getValue() returns null.

Comment: Please only use your *exact* code here. I am pretty sure the above code was not copy-pasted.

Answer (score 3):

1. What's the point of catching a `NullPointerException`? When do you expect it to happen?
2. I don't really like that this method mutates the list passed in as a parameter - and then also returns it, even though the returned value is actually redundant as the calling code already has a hold of the now modified list. You're kind of sharing the result of the operation in two ways at once, which feels redundant.

   And I know it's often done that way, but I think it's bad practice nevertheless, and can lead to confusion.

   Personally I'd prefer to be more explicit about what's going on, and either **a)** make a deep copy of the original list, and return an independent version of it (with entries removed), without affecting the original one - or **b)** make this method `void`, like [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)).

   See [command-query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) principle. Making a method look like a query can lead me to believe it's a pure function, with no side effects, whereas it actually does cause side effects, mutating the input data.
3. The name is very vague - "remove", remove what?
4. Is the blacklisted data ("FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD") likely to ever change? In the spirit of making this code more modular I would consider extracting that list to a separate parameter.

   [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) indicates that a method should have one clear responsibility, and one could argue that filtering out certain entries and *knowing* the blacklist are two responsibilities. Your mileage may vary though, depending on the cnotext - which I don't know.
5. Not a biggie, but whitespace is out of control (`iterator.hasNext();     )`, `catch(NUllPointerException e){}`), not to mention it's `NullPointer...`, not `NUllPointer`.
6. Depending on how `Column` class is implemented, which I can't see - if it's a light-weight object and if its `equals()` method would compare `Column` instances by their value (`getValue()`)... then we could leverage [Collections.removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) and save ourselves writing the iterative removal by hand.

Eg. assuming

```
class Column {
    private final String value;

    public Column(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // if a Column instance, compare it by value
    }

    // don't forget hashCode
}
```

we could just do that:

```
/* could be a Set actually since order doesn't matter,
 * only Set hasn't got such a convenient initializer in standard Java API */
private static final Collection<Column> BLACKLISTED_COLUMNS = Arrays.asList(
    new Column("FIRST"), 
    new Column("SECOND"), 
    new Column("THIRD"));
```

be it a constant, or a collection computed in run-time, doesn't really matter. And then it gets as simple as that:

```
List<Column> columns = // ... getting the data from wherever
columns.removeAll(BLACKLISTED_COLUMNS);
```

And that's it, job done. As I said, this solution may not be applicable in your case - I have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [removeIf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)?

Write Your `Predicate` class:

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;

class SamplePredicate<T> implements Predicate<T> {
  HashSet<String> exclude = new HashSet<>();

  public boolean test(T column) {
    return this.exclude.contains(column.getValue());
  }
}
```

and use it:

```
SamplePredicate<Column> filter = new SamplePredicate<>();
filter.exclude.add("FIRST");
filter.exclude.add("SECOND");
filter.exclude.add("THIRD");

columns.removeIf(filter);
```

---

Or streams

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

List<String> predicate = Arrays.asList("FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD");

columns = oclumns.stream()
    .filter(column -> !predicate.contains(column.getValue()))
    .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

Comment: Instead of `ArrayList` it could be faster with `HashSet`. Instead of writing a class for the `Predicate`, you could use a Lambda. `columns.stream.filter(col -> !exclude.contains(col.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: You `removeIf` guys are lucky with Java >=8. (It looks like some disturbing emoticon, but I just meant "8 and higher"). As an Android Java dev, stuck at the rough equivalent of Java 6, I'm missing these functional features. You can still get them, but only with libraries (like Retrolambda, Guava etc.) which couldn't be recommended for a single-use case.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the constant FIRST, SECOND etc? Just put them in a constant structure if you only need the values.

Secondly, use Java's built-in methods for collections, lists, etc.

Thirdly, as use use a thrd party lib, you need to be extra defensive with it.

```
public static final Set<String> REMOVAL_VALUES = new HashSet<>();
static {
    REMOVAL_VALUES.add("first to remove");
    REMOVAL_VALUES.add("second to remove");
    REMOVAL_VALUES.add("third to remove");
}

public void method() {
    List<Column> columns = ThirdPartyLibrary.getColumns();

    if (columns == null) {
         //handle this case as you get it from a thrd party
    }

    columns.removeIf(c -> REMOVAL_VALUES.contains(c.getValue()));
    // do something with columns.
}
```

Comment: You're missing an assignment operator here: `List<Column> columns ThirdPartyLibrary`, I'd edit it in myself, but someone decided edits must modify at least 6 characters (great idea, 6 is a well known magical threshold for useful edits). Not that it matters much ;)

Comment: @KonradMorawski thanks, I'll fix it right away